# `a_{ij}+b_{kj}=c_{ik}` contraction in torch

Tags: pytorch

Title is self explanatory. I need to work out this weird contraction in torch. Adding a row vector and column vector can do `a_i+b_j=c_{ij}`, which is close, but I haven't been able to generalize it. This site doesn't like short questions so enjoy this useless sentence.

Comment: The word limitation is there to ensure a question is associated with sufficient debugging details so it can be answered, which is absent in this question. You should explain your question by providing your current attempt, expected output, and error message(if any). Please learn the rule of the site before calling it toxic.

Comment: @olafcx please review [ask].

Comment: Whoever deleted my message where I point out that this question abides by the rules just fine, and where I point out how toxic it is to dislike a question for no other reason than it being short, should really get a clue. You are the problem, this place doesn't have to be toxic.

Comment: I'll ask again, let's see if it gets deleted again. I wrote my attempt. The expected output is the title, implicit index sum notation is perfectly clear. There is no error message. What do you want from me, both of you? Complexity is not something that should be worshipped. A simple question does not need to be long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating empty dimension in a tensor summation auto-copies the value across the dimension on other tensor. Here is the contraction of summation you probably want.

```
(A.unsqueeze(0) + B.unsqueeze(1)).sum(-1)
```

Update: I misunderstood your question in my previous einsum answer.

Comment: No, I am not looking for `a_{ij}b_{kj}`, I am looking for `a_{ij}+b_{kj}`, like the question asks.

Comment: Okay, I misunderstood your question and I updated my answer accordingly. I'm just trying to help. I understand your frustration, but you don't have to make a personal attack on me pointing out my name in your comment above like that.